# Monopoly: Positions

Tags: javascript, game

I want to know if this can be trimmed down further. I am repeating myself with `this.title` and `this.position`. Also `this.position` is the corresponding array index, not sure if that is a good idea, if player throws 3 then perhaps I can just denote that as player is currently at `positions[3]`. I use `this.price` instead of `this.rent` because otherwise I would have 2 different object properties, `purchaseprice` and `rentprice`, I felt I could merge the 2 into 1 property and use an array.

Looking forward to suggestions.

**Positions**

```
positions = [
    new Position("Go", 0),
    new Cities("Cairo", "brown", [60, 2, 10, 30, 90, 160, 250], 1),
    new CardPosition("Chest", "chest", 2),
    new Cities("Vienna", "brown", [60, 4, 20, 60, 180, 320, 450], 3),
    new Tax("Income Tax", 200, 4),
    new Airport("Schiphol", [200, 25, 50, 100, 200], 5),
    new Cities("Brussels", "blue", [100, 6, 30, 90, 270, 400, 550], 6),
    new CardPosition("Chance", "chance", 7),
    new Cities("Stockholm", "blue", [100, 6, 30, 90, 270, 400, 550], 8),
    new Cities("Geneva", "blue", [120, 8, 40, 100, 300, 450, 600], 9),
    new Position("Jailhouse", 10),
    new Cities("Amsterdam", "pink", [140, 10, 50, 150, 450, 625, 750], 11),
    new Position("Electric", 12),
    new Cities("Bangkok", "pink", [140, 10, 50, 150, 450, 625, 750], 13),
    new Cities("Istanbul", "pink", [160, 12, 60, 180, 500, 700, 900], 14),
    new Airport("DBX", [200, 25, 50, 100, 200], 15),
    new Cities("Hong Kong", "orange", [180, 14, 70, 200, 550, 750, 950], 16),
    new CardPosition("Chest", "chest", 17),
    new Cities("Madrid", "orange", [180, 14, 70, 200, 550, 750, 950], 18),
    new Cities("Sydney", "orange", [200, 14, 70, 200, 550, 750, 950], 19),
    new Position("Free Parking", 20),
    new Cities("Toronto", "red", [220, 18, 90, 250, 700, 875, 1050], 21),
    new CardPosition("Chance", "chance", 22),
    new Cities("Mumbai", "red", [220, 18, 90, 250, 700, 875, 1050], 23),
    new Cities("Rome", "red", [240, 20, 100, 300, 750, 925, 1100], 24),
    new Airport("BCN", [200, 25, 50, 100, 200], 25),
    new Cities("Rio", "yellow", [260, 22, 110, 330, 800, 975, 1150], 26),
    new Cities("Tokyo", "yellow", [260, 22, 110, 330, 800, 975, 1150], 27),
    new Position("Water Works", 28),
    new Cities("Paris", "yellow", [280, 24, 120, 360, 850, 1025, 1200], 29),
    new Position("Go to Jail", 30),
    new Cities("Berlin", "green", [300, 26, 130, 390, 900, 1100, 1275], 31),
    new Cities("Bejing", "green", [300, 26, 130, 390, 900, 1100, 1275], 32),
    new CardPosition("Chest", "chest", 33),
    new Cities("Moscow", "green", [320, 28, 150, 450, 1000, 1200, 1400], 34),
    new Airport("LAX", [200, 25, 50, 100, 200], 35),
    new CardPosition("Chance", "chance", 36),
    new Cities("New York", "navy", [350, 35, 175, 500, 1100, 1300, 1500], 37),
    new Tax("Super Tax", 100, 38),
    new Cities("London", "navy", [400, 50, 200, 600, 1400, 1700, 2000], 39)
];

function Position (title,position){
    this.title = title;
    this.position = position;
    this.forsale = false;
}
function CardPosition (title,type,position){
    this.title = title;
    this.type = type;
    this.position = position;
    this.forsale = false;
}
function Tax (title,tax,position){
    this.title = title;
    this.tax = tax;
    this.position = position;
    this.forsale = false;
    this.type = "tax";
}
function Airport(title,prices,position){
    this.title = title;
    this.rating = 0;
    this.price = prices[this.rating];
    this.position = position;
    this.forsale = true;
    this.type = "airport";
}
function Cities (title,set,prices,position){
    this.title = title;
    this.set = set;
    this.rating = 0;
    this.prices = prices;
    this.price = prices[this.rating];
    this.position = position;
    this.owner = "unowned";
    this.forsale = true;
    this.type = "city";
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few places that I think you could simplify the code, but I don't think you are too far off.  Let me address each concern:

1. > I am repeating myself with `this.title` and `this.position`.

   You can set all of these classes up in a class hierarchy, so that they can share common attributes.  By using the `.call()` method, you can set up superclasses, and then reference them them as part of your subclass constructor.  For example, **ignoring any other changes**, your first two classes can be reduced to a superclass and a subclass, like this:

   ```
   function Position(title, position) {
       this.title = title;
       this.position = position;
       this.forsale = false;
   }

   function CardPosition(title, type, position) {
       Position.call(this, title, position);
       this.type = type;
   }
   ```
2. > Also `this.position` is the corresponding array index, not sure if that
   >   is a good idea, if player throws 3 then perhaps I can just denote that
   >   as player is currently at `positions[3]`.

   If the positions will always be in the order that they are stored in the array, then, yes, there is no reason to store the position as part of each object . . . the position in the array **is** the position of the "card", so storing the value in the object would be redundant.  I'd remove all of the `position` attributes from the entire class structure.
3. > I use `this.price` instead of `this.rent` because otherwise I would have 2
   >   different object properties, `purchaseprice` and `rentprice`, I felt I
   >   could merge the 2 into 1 property and use an array.

   Looking at your sample data, I would keep these two prices separate.  What you have is one purchase price and a series of scaling rent prices.  It makes sense to use an array for the rents (because the are multiple values for the same piece of data), but the purchase price is different data and should really remain separate from the rent array.

   However, see my third "additional suggestion" below, for another way to group them . . .
4. I'd also have a few of other comments/suggestions, that might streamline your code:

   - make `forsale` part of `Position` and pass the value in as a parameter.  All of the subclasses under it have a `forsale` attribute in common.
   - assuming that "airports" are like "railroads", in Monopoly, don't they also need a `owner` property?
   - you could consider another superclass called something like "DevelopmentProperties" as a parent of any subclass that has `pricing`, `rent`, `rating`, and `owner` values, in order to consolidate the data that is common to purchasable, update-able properties.

You could set `DevelopmentProperties` up like this:

```
function DevelopmentProperties(price, rents) {
    this.price = price;
    this.rents = rents;
    this.rating = 0;
    this.owner = "unowned";
}
```

. . . and extend it using this:

```
    DevelopmentProperties.call(this, price, rents);
```

### So, finally . . .

Putting all of that together, here is how the code would end up:

```
// first, the common, top-level superclasses
function Position(title, forsale) {
    this.title = title;
    this.forsale = forsale;
}

function DevelopmentProperties(price, rents) {
    this.price = price;
    this.rents = rents;
    this.rating = 0;
    this.owner = "unowned";
}

// next, a mid-level subclass, that also acts as a superclass for the subclasses below
function CardPosition(title, type, forsale) {
    Position.call(this, title, forsale);
    this.type = type;
}

// finally, the low-level, subclasses that extend the superclasses above them
function Tax(title, tax) {
    CardPosition.call(this, title, "tax", false);
    this.tax = tax;
}

function Airport(title, price, rents) {
    CardPosition.call(this, title, "airport", true);
    DevelopmentProperties.call(this, purchase, rents);
}

function Cities(title, set, price, rents) {
    CardPosition.call(this, title, "city", true);
    DevelopmentProperties.call(this, purchase, rents);
    this.set = set;
}
```

I didn't update the `positions` array, but, obviously, that would also need to be updated a little bit to match the new structure.

Hope that helps!   :)

Comment: I am working on this might take me a while, but I have one question. I know that `forsale` is common but it is tedious to add it in every line since its default value will be false. So can the `Position` superclass set `forsale` to false for all its subclasses?

Comment: You could, but you do have two instances (`Airport` and `Cities`) where the value defaults to `true` . . . would be nice to be able to pass that in.  You could set it up to be an "optional" parameter . . . change `this.forsale = forsale` to `this.forsale = forsale || false;` . . . that way, it would default to `false`, but would still assign the value, if it was provided.  It's even at the right position in the parameters already, so it could just be left off for `false` values . . . the lines would only need to updated if it was ever `true` and wasn't an `Airport` or `Cities` object.

Comment: maybe `!!forsale` instead? The goal is to convert to boolean, correct? So why not say _that_ instead of saying "convert to boolean and then do a no-op"?

Comment: @TimSeguine - actually, I was assuming that the value (if present) would be Boolean already.  Elton didn't want to have to pass `false` for all of the cards that were not "buyable", when creating their objects. The logic was to make it so that if the parameter was left out (`undefined`) or set to `null`, the value of `forsale` in the object would default to `false`.

Comment: Okay I recognized then correctly, my argument stands. The thing is: if `forsale` is a boolean then `forsale || false` is a no-op (Or'ing with false is the identity). If `forsale` is not a boolean, then `forsale || false` converts it to one, then performs a no-op.

Comment: But, if he used `!!forsale`, wouldn't that also be performing an unnecessary "double not" on both `true` and `false` values?  Seems like the other way, at least only one of those values has the extra operation performed on it.

Comment: On a side note, I think we have to assume that the value passed in is a Boolean . . . if not, more logic is required, since `!!forsale` would return `true` for a string value of `"false"` and `forsale || false` would return the actual string values, rather than a Boolean.

Answer (score 6):

Some minor remarks:

- Your `Cities` class should be called `City`
- If you are willing to use falsey boolean checks, you do not need to initialize `forsale` to false
- I would store the prices separately:

  ```
  var rentPrices =  [
    "brown" : {
      low : [2, 10, 30, 90, 160, 250],
      high : [60, 4, 20, 60, 180, 320, 450]
    },
    "blue" : {
      low : [6, 30, 90, 270, 400, 550],
      high : [8, 40, 100, 300, 450, 600]
    }
  //etc. etc.
  ]
  ```

  This way you can indicate the rent prices by providing whether the card should charge low or high rent for that color ( Geneva is high, Stockholm and Brussels are low ). Otherwise you repeat the low price in your positions table for all but brown and navy.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is actually not too bad, in my opinion.

The `title` and `position` parameters are common to all of the positions, so put them consistently as the first two arguments.  (It's common practice in many languages to put "optional" parameters last.)

My first instinctual criticism would be that the `position` parameter is redundant, since it can be inferred from the element's index in the array.  However, I should point out that there is a "Jail" and a "Just Visiting" space, both at position 10.  Therefore, when you eventually get around to implementing the Jail/Visitor split, you will eventually need to have the position explicitly defined.

Comment: that's a good thought on the jail space.however, it might be worth considering that space to be simply just visiting, and maintain a flag to indicate whether the player is in jail or not.  To me, in jail, is more a state of the player than it is a position on the board

Comment: @heiserman couldn't have put that  any better. The player is either inJail or justVisiting but in either case the player is @ Jailhouse.